# Can we make Pres *-autonomous?

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

The category $\mathbf{Sup}$ of sup-lattices (posets admitting all supremum and supremum preserving map between them) is a well known example of a $*$-autonomous category:

The internal Hom is simply the set of supremum preserving map with the pointwise ordering between them, map $X \otimes Y \to Z$ corresponds to order preserving map $X \times Y \to Z$ that preserves supremum in each variable, the $*$-involution takes a poset $P$ to its opposite ordering and map $f:P \to Q$ to its right adjoint, seen as a supremum preserving map $Q^\text{op} \to P^\text{op}$. The dualizing object is $\Omega^\text{op}$, with $\Omega$ the subobject classifier (so $\{0,1\}$).

In particular, the tensor product can be described by the usual:

$$ X \otimes Y = \text{Hom}(X,Y^\text{op})^\text{op} $$

i.e. as the set of infimum preserving maps $X^\text{op} \to Y$.

The category $\mathbf{Sup}$ is the category of "locally presentable posets, i.e. locally presentable $(0,1)$-categories". But as soon as we move one step up the categorical ladder, to the (bi)category $\mathbf{Pres}$ of locally presentable categories and colimit preserving (equivalently, left adjoint) functors between them, we no longer have a $*$-autonomous category.

Still much of this structure is still present on $\mathbf{Pres}$: It is a monoidal closed category, where the internal hom is given by the category of all left adjoint functor $C \to D$. The tensor product was constructed by Bird (see section 5 of [his thesis](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/BirdPhD.pdf)) following previous work of Kelly, and is such that colimit preserving functors $C \otimes D \to E$ are the same as functors $C \times D \to E$ preserving colimits in each separate variables.

And in fact, $\mathbf{Pres}$ still feel very much like a $*$-autonomous category, again with opposite category and taking right adjoint as the $*$-involution, in the sense that we still have formulas like:

$$ \text{Ladj}(C,\text{Set}^\text{op}) \simeq C^\text{op} $$
$$ C \otimes D \simeq \text{Ladj}(C,D^\text{op})^\text{op}$$

But it is *not* a $*$-autonomous category for the good reason that the opposite a locally presentable category is almost never locally presentable (it is if and only if it is an object of $\mathbf{Sup} actually).

My question is, *can we modify $\mathbf{Pres}$ (by adding new objects) to make it a $*$-autonomous category in a nice way ?*

I am relatively open about the sort of category (let's call it $\mathbf{A}$) I want, here is a list of the type of properties I would like to have.

- $\mathbf{A}$ should be a $*$-autonomous category.
- $\mathbf{A}$ should contains $\mathbf{Pres}$ as a monoidal full subcategory, closed under exponential.

But I still would like objects of $\mathbf{A}$ to be category in some sense:
, and the formula above fits into a $*$-autonomous structure of $\mathbf{A}$:

- $\mathbf{A}$ should have a forgetfull functor $U$ to the category of categories and left adjoint functor between them.
- $U$ restricted to $\mathbf{Pres}$ should be the obvious functor.
- $U(C^*)$ should be $C^\text{op}$ and if $F$ is a functor $U(F^*)$ should be a right adjoint of $U(F)$.

I don't think it is reasonable to expect that $U$ could be fully faithful, so I'm fine with $\mathbf{A}$ being a category of "category with structure", as long as $U$ is fully faithful on $\mathbf{Pres}$.

$\mathbf{Pres}$ is also known to have all small limits and colimits, I would like these to be preserved by the inclusion to $\mathbf{A}$. I don't think it is reasonable to expect that $\mathbf{A}$ will have all small limits and colimits as well, but the more it has the better.

Any negative results showing that this whish list, or some other reasonable wish list is too strong would also be greatly appreciated.

*Precision:* I'm aware of Mike Shulman recent [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.08487) showing that any monoidal closed category can be fully faithfuly embeded in a $*$-autonomous category, with an embedding preserving tensor product and exponential (and even some colimits). In fact I had this question in mind for a long time, but I've thinking about it again recently because of this preprint.

So, assuming Mike's construction apply to $\mathbf{Pres}$, despite it not being a $1$-category nor locally small, that is definitely a good place to start. But I havn't really been able to parse what this construction would give in this case, nor if it comes with a forgetful functor to Cat. Also, I got the impression that this construction was maybe to general for this example ? Any comment on this would also be very welcome.

Comment: I disagree with you, Simon. The analogue of Sup is the 2-category of cocomplete categories. It happens that a cocomplete poset is complete, thus the opposite of a suplattice is a suplattice. For categories, you could maintain the analogy by looking at complete and cocomplete categories. Notice that even in Cat a cocomplete category is always very close to be complete (Adamek et al: Cocompleteness almost implies completeness).

Comment: The fact that loc. pres. categories are complete is just a phenomenon of the more general pattern that every total category is complete. The generator forces the limits to exist computing them as "sups of lower bounds".

Comment: Ok, let say that what I really mean is that the $0$-categorical analogue of $\mathbf{Pres}$ is $\mathbf{Sup}$, which I think you will agree with. I could argue that the $0$-categorical analogue of the category $\mathbf{CoComp}$ of co-complete categories is really the category $\mathbf{SUP}$ of possibly *large* posets having supremum of small families, which would contradict what you say. Though these matters are somehow subjective, so I guess we can agree to disagree ^^

Comment: Ahah, you are somehow missing my point. The 2-category of complete and cocomplete categories (and cocontinuous functors) is $*$-autonomous replacing adjoints with (co)continuous functors. The existence of a generator in a loc. pres category just makes the whole situation tamer. In a way, I am claiming that you already have the answer, you just care too much about (co)generating sets and smallness assumptions. From my point of view, we agree to agree.

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment. There exists a very natural fully faithful embedding of $\textbf{Pres}$ in a $*$-autonomous category preserving the monoidal closed structure. That is the inclusion of $\textbf{Pres}$ in the (2-)category of complete and cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors.

Comment: Is it ? I don't think the tensor product of complete & co-complete categories is defined. Also if you want 'op' to be a contravariant functor you need morphisms to have right adjoint.

Comment: You are just right, I'll be thinking about this. One could try to fix what I said in a technical way (choosing only left adjoints, choosing total categories instead of complete and cocomplete ones), but I will try to come back with a more mature observation before shooting in the sky.